# JSP JQuery show div after logout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp, redirect

I have a jsp website that has a menu bar. Upon clicking the logout button, the page redirects to the welcome jsp page. However, I hope to make it so that once the user clicks logout, the welcome page now has a div with some span that reads "You have successfully logged out". I have been trying to get this to work, but to no avail.

In my javascript, I start with a globally defined variable, and have two related functions.

```
logoutDeterminant = "no";

function determine(word) {
   if (word == "yes")
   {
       logoutDeterminant = "yes";
       alert(logoutDeterminant);
    }
}

function showLogoutNotification() {
   if (logoutDeterminant = "yes") {
       alert(logoutDeterminant);
       //toggle the class
   }
}
```

The global variable logout determinant starts with no. When the welcome jsp loads, it runs showLogoutNotification, which means the global variable is assigned no, and the class for the div on the page is not toggled. The div is the successful logout notification, and there is a class that hides it. So the toggle doesnt work, and the hidden class isn't removed.

Once the user enters the main page, and then clicks logout, the function 
determine("yes") runs on click, setting the logoutDeterminant to "yes".

Now, when the welcome page loads again, I imagined that it would've registered logout determinant as yes, and therefore toggled the class. However, it comes out as no. This leads me to believe that the javascript resets when the page changes, and so logout determinant is again "no".

How would one go about making the logout notification on the same welcome page? I have access to java via jsp servlets, jquery/javascript, html, and such.

Comment: Why did you tagged jsp here? What you have done is entirely javascript.

Comment: I apologize. The pages I am working on are JSP. I thought that might be relevant.  I apologize if that was inaccurate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the message as request parameter

```
String message = "logged out successfully";
response.sendRedirect("mypage.jsp?message=" + URLEncoder.encode(message, "UTF-8"));
```

so that you can display it in JSP as follows

```
<span id="myMessage">${param.message}</span>
```

use your javascript/jQuery wisely to hide the message in few minutes,

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#myMessage').fadeOut('fast');
}, 1000); // <-- time in milliseconds
```

you may use `fadeOut()` or just `hide()`.

Comment: Also, if this were to work... and the logout notification was eventually hidden, if the user refreshed the page it would run the timeout function again and show the logout notification for  a few seconds wouldn't it?

Comment: I got it to work. Is there a way to remove the entire span of the word after refreshing?

Comment: yes, you can remove using `remove()` method in jquery.